# How to convert this mongodb object to normal version?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, electron

I'm using electron and react to work my application which communicate each other with ipcMain and ipcRenderer. I don't use a backend with express library. I'm using mongodb with mongoose to model collections. I have an array of objects db objects emitted from electron and on the client(react) side it gives a single object like this.

```
availability: true
bID: "A-Block"
dateCreated: Wed Aug 19 2020 16:18:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
__v: 0
_id: {_bsontype: "ObjectID", id: Uint8Array(12)}
__proto__: Object
```

I want the actual object on the client side too which is my problem.

Below is my MongooseModel.find() method

```
loadBuildings: (callback) => {
    Building.find().lean().then(bs => callback(bs))
}
```

It gives the supposed object as I want it in the console. Like this.

```
_id: 5f3d0384c42b9eee83b59762,
availability: true,
bID: 'A-Block',
dateCreated: 2020-08-19T10:48:36.051Z,
__v: 0
```

How to get the same object without additional meta key-values on the react-side? Help!

Answer (score 1):

check [find Projections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projections)

The projection parameter specifies which fields to return. The parameter contains either include or exclude specifications, not both, unless the exclude is for the _id field.

```
loadBuildings: (callback) => {
    Building.find({ }, { availability: 1, bID: 1, dateCreated: 1 }).lean().then(bs => callback(bs))
}
```